# Получение html кода страницы,Get запрос на WinSock Delphi

Tags: delphi, парсер, winapi, winsock

Необходимо получить html код страницы, где в дальнейшем надо будет искать ссылку на картинку

Работаю через winsock, запрос отправляю следующим образом:

```
SendStr(stClient, 'GET '+addr+' HTTP/1.1'+#13+#10+'Content-Type:text/html'
    +#13+#10+'User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0;Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; 
    .NET CLR 2.0.50727)'
    +#13+#10+'Host: '+testingserver+#13+#10+'Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive'+#13+#10+#13+#10);
```

где, stClient - мой сокет, а addr - непосредственно адрес сайта

Но вот незадача, у меня парсится лишь сайт гугла, а при выборе другого сайта выдает ошибку: "404 - Bad Request"

Хотелось бы узнать в чем может быть проблема, и какой запрос все же следует отправлять, для получения корректного ответа?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "непосредственно адрес сайта"? Сравните формат своих `addr` и `testingserver` с примером из спецификации https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.4

Comment: по типу: "https://www.goоgle.com" - это моя переменная addr (URL страницы) (с использованием "https://" комментарии эту часть не отображают)

А "www.google.com" - моя переменная testingServer, (это имя сервера)

Comment: Согласно документации в таком запросе `addr` должен быть равен `/`

Comment: @ГерманБорисов
Я не совсем понял что вы имели ввиду, в документации сказано: 'OPTIONS http://www.example.org:8001 HTTP/1.1
   would be forwarded by the final proxy as
     OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1'
В финальной версии запроса у меня получается строка вида:
['https://www.google.com HTTP/1.1'], все как в документации

Comment: При чем тут метод `OPTIONS`, если у вас в вопросе метод `GET`?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов
Прошу,прощения,привел не ту цитату
Но сути дела это не меняет, если я пытаюсь получить код главной страницы гугла, то я должен указать полный URL страницы в качестве адреса, а в качестве хоста лишь 'google.com'
Да и с гуглом все работает, а вот с другими сайтами - нет

Answer (score 0):

Выдержка из документа https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230 с переводом

3.1.1. Первая строка имеет вид: `Метод Цель HTTP/версия`

5.3. Цель может иметь один из 4-х форматов (см 5.3.1 … 5.3.4)

5.3.1. Если метод не `CONNECT` и не `OPTIONS`, и запрос не к прокси, а непосредственно к серверу, то в качестве цели указывается путь и запрос (но не имя хоста).

Если путь пуст, то вместо него передается передается `/`

Например, если нужно получить документ `http://www.example.org/where?q=now`, следует установить TCP-соединение с [www.example.org](http://www.example.org) и выполнить запрос:

```
 GET /where?q=now HTTP/1.1
 Host: www.example.org
```

Таким образом в вашем случае переменная `addr` должна содержать только то, что правее имени хоста в URL. Если там ничего нет, то `/`

Comment: Чьорт, ошибка была совершенно в другом месте, но спасибо за ответ, большее понимание пришло) Правда вот код страницы теперь не весь отображается(не так как в инспекторе объектов браузера), но с этим,скорее всего, разберусь